# Datatables data refresh based on user input parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

**Goal**

I need generate/refresh table from the input parameters from an user.

- Iam using datatables (1.10.7) jquery plugin.

**User input**

[image]

**Table**

```
<table class="display" id="table1" cellspacing="0">           
</table>
```

**DataTable script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#table1').DataTable({

        /* SERVER SIDE PROCESSING */
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":
            {
                "url": "Home/Search",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {
                    'NumberType': '<NumberType>', /* How pass this from function ? */
                    'Number': '<Number>' /* How pass this from function ? */
                }
            }

    });

} );
</script>
```

**Question**

1) How can I input returned value from function in ajax "data" parameter?

The Idea is that function will return NumberType and Number value from the textboxes in the POST request to server side process.

2) What event I can call to refresh the ajax server side source ?

Something like

```
$('#table1').DataTable.Reload()
```

Thank you

Comment: `'NumberType': $('#NumberType1').val()` Assuming your input has an id of `NumberType1`. Calling `draw()` on the table will pass the data parameters to the server in the request.

Comment: I don't know which textbox will be filled but I assume I can use function directly then ? GetNumberType(). I will try the draw function ! Thank you

Comment: What is GetNumberType()?

Comment: The function which will return the NumberType (NumberType1 or NumberType2) because I need to know which textbox the user entered. And this value is parameter for server side process.